# multiple ids in one get element javascript

Tags: javascript

now, this is ugly, how do I put them together in 1 row

```
function side1() {
  document.getElementById('side-open1').classList.remove('side-open-dpn');
  document.getElementById('item-link1').classList.add('side-open-dpn');
  document.getElementById('item-link2').classList.add('side-open-dpn');
  document.getElementById('item-link3').classList.add('side-open-dpn');
  document.getElementById('item-link4').classList.add('side-open-dpn');
  document.getElementById('item-link5').classList.add('side-open-dpn');
}
function back1() {
  document.getElementById('side-open1').classList.add('side-open-dpn');
  document.getElementById('item-link1').classList.remove('side-open-dpn');
  document.getElementById('item-link2').classList.remove('side-open-dpn');
  document.getElementById('item-link3').classList.remove('side-open-dpn');
  document.getElementById('item-link4').classList.remove('side-open-dpn');
  document.getElementById('item-link5').classList.remove('side-open-dpn');
}
```

i want the item-link(1;5) to be selected together, tried querlySelectroAll too, but maybe i did someting wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select multiple elements by ID in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096600/select-multiple-elements-by-id-in-one-line)

Comment: also see: [getElementById() wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275071/getelementbyid-wildcard)

Comment: This is what the `class` attribute is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick them with their ids, sice all of their ids starts with `item-link`, you can use `document.querySelectorAll("[id^='item-link']")`

`"[id^='item-link']"` will select all elements whose id starts with `item-link`

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='item-link']");
console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div id="item-link1"></div>
<div id="item-link2"></div>
<div id="item-link3"></div>
<div id="item-link4"></div>
<div id="item-link5"></div>
```

Comment: This is covered in the second duplicate listed as well as here [wildcard * in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes). Please flag for closure.